# Should I use lighter or heavier paper for my printed dissertation?

Tags: thesis

My university requires one to submit a printed copy of the dissertation. The paper has to be 100% cotton, white, and 20- to 24 lb weight.

Since I have a choice in the weight of the paper, my question is if there are any advantages to one weight over the other.

Comment: Go to the print shop. And ask to see if you can see/feel samples of different weight paper. (Better yet, see/feel documents printed on different weight paper.) I would say that the difference is certainly noticeable, but it is up to you whether the difference is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lighter paper is usually slightly cheaper. And your finished book would be also lighter (pretty much by definition); this may or may not make a difference for when you carry it to the various offices/libraries as part of the process of finishing your degree.

Heavier paper has a better "feel" when you flip pages (think about the difference between a high quality hardcover book versus a cheap paper-back novel). It is a bit more resistant to wear and tear, and if you scan/photocopy pages it will be less likely to have the effect where the "next" page shows through.

---

If the only publicly available copy of your dissertation would be the copy you submit, I would ask you to do would-be readers a favor and use heavier paper. But if you intend to publish your thesis (take chapters and publish them as journal articles, or just put the entire thesis online for the world to see), then the lighter paper will save you a little money, and perhaps be marginally better on the environment.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the weight of the paper is as important as the material from which it is made. So long as the paper is "archival quality," meaning no acids or other components which will allow it to degrade more easily over time, the choice is somewhat arbitrary. Willie Wong raises some valid points in his answer, though—the slightly thicker paper will help future readers more than the thinner paper, and the relative change in weight is probably not so large as to make the thesis cumbersome as a printed volume.

Comment: This is exactly what I decided to get...until I tried to find A4 paper in the US. The three options available didn't include "archival quality". Still, +1 for the info.